# Angular js - formatting datetime to match condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetime, format, locale

Hi i'm simply printing out datetime using the Angular date filter and this is how my code looks actually:

```
<small class="muted smaller">

        {{row.insert_datetime |  date : 'shortTime'}},
        {{row.insert_datetime | date : 'longDate'}}
    </small>
```

so the result is pretty good and it returns :

```
<small class="muted smaller">
            5:22 PM, 1 April 2010
</small>
```

What i would like more is to return something like this with conditions:

```
if(today == 1 April 2010){
print 5:22 PM
}else{
print 5:22 PM , 1 April 2010
}
```

Is it possible in some way to add this condition  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use angular filter concept , you can modify this to further to achieve your goal

```
angular.module('yourmodule').filter('hbdate', function($filter)
{
    return function(input)
    {
        if(input == null){ return ""; }
        var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'MMM dd yyyy');
                if{
                 your condition 
                 }

        return _date.toUpperCase();
    };
});
```

[Date filtering and formatting in Angular js.](http://angulartutorial.blogspot.in/2014/04/date-filtering-and-formatting-in.html)

Comment: +1 cool right i'll try it out and accept your answer if no better ones :D thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It is doable as:

```
<span>
    {{ row.insert_datetime |  date : 'shortTime' }}
    {{ row.insert_datetime === today && ' ' || (',' + (row.insert_datetime | date : 'longDate')) }}
</span>
```

But it is ugly; maybe you should try doing it in code. (If you do it, note the space in the string after the `&&` - it is needed.)

Comment: what is today in your case sorry ?

Comment: `today` is something that can be compared to `row.insert_datetime`; a date set to the current date. The comparison will have to ignore time, you may want to check out [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/).